# Milch? Milsh? Why the pronunciation difference?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm working my way through the Pimsleur German series, and I've noticed that one of the speakers has what seems to me a strange pronunciation of the word *Milch*.

He pronounces the *ch* like the *sh* sound in *wish* (in English), that is, the IPA sound ʃ.  I would've thought it's pronounced like the IPA ç.

Is this common?  Is it specific to certain areas of the German-speaking world?  Or is it, in fact, the "correct" pronunciation?

Comment: There are even German pepole who can’t make the *ch* sound. My maths teacher for example couldn’t do it and always made a *sch* sound.

Comment: Anecdote: a childhood friend of mine (native speaker) consistently pronounced “Milch” as /milʃ/ and “Fleisch” as /flaɪç/. That is, exactly the wrong way round. Apparently, this is rather common.

Comment: Our palatinate ex-chancellor Kohl is famous for replacing too many of the /ʃ/ in his native dialect by /ç/, e.g. in "Gechichte".

Comment: @KonradRudolph In my native _Rheinland_, I've seen this quite often. It is especially confusing with _Kirsche_ and _Kirche_.

Comment: Kohl's problem was a hypercorrection. His home region (Palatinate) is close to France, and due to French influence /ç/ doesn't exist there. As a result, people from that region may sound very uneducated when speaking standard German. It was obviously important to him to get all /ç/ sounds right. But since for the first years of his life /ç/ was equivalent to /ʃ/ to him, he sometimes subconsciously replaced /ʃ/ by /ç/. The same thing sometimes happens to me. I always notice it immediately, and it feels very awkward.

Comment: I rly struggle to pronounce the sequence/lç/and so I end up pronouncing Milch like /mɪɬ/ instead of/mɪlç/, I've tried /mɪlx/ or /mɪlχ/ but that just feels like rly weird and unnatural mouth gymnastics.

Comment: @Hænæt Let the sides of your tonge make contact with your upper molars, with very little tension on the tip of the tongue, and the "ch" comes out naturally. ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

/mɪlç/ is Standard German. The other one is most likely the result of the speaker having an accent. Some German dialects, e.g. Swabian (however obviously not in this case according to the comments :-) ), often pronounce *ch* as the IPA sound /ʃ/. And native speakers with that dialect often can't drop that habit even if they try to speak Standard German.

[Edit: Corrected based on comment]

Comment: Being Swabian I can definitely say that 'ch' is pronounced /ç/ here. We do not pronounced it /ʃ/ (at least in most regions).

Comment: It's often pronounced ʃ in Saxony, but then the ɪ would usually be different, too. ;) (Don't know the IPA sign for the vowel used instead, sorry.)

Comment: I second what @Takkat says - it's not `/ʃ/` in any Swabian dialect (nor any other of the Alemannic ones I think). It's really strong in Hessian, Badenian, and Pfälzisch.

Comment: And Saarländisch.

Comment: @Pekka: thanks for clarification. I know it is unforgivable ^^ but most Germans outside those regions don't know the difference between Swabians and Badenians at all. So that's probably the reason why everyone thinks the /ʃ/ is Swabian. ;-)

Comment: @starblue true! @ladybug I don't mind - but don't make that mistake in a swabian (or, probably, Badenian) pub! ;)

Comment: ... and Kölsch. You wouldn't believe how hard it is to pronounce "Küchentisch" in correct Standard German, if you've learned German in the Rhine Area.

Comment: @teylyn: Hehe. I remember my mum struggeling with "Griechische Geschichte" when she used to have singing lessons. ^^

Comment: It _could_ also be a case of hypercorrection. At least both the [German](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperkorrektur#Beispiele_im_Deutschen) and the [English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection#German) Wikipedia mention the ç/ʃ confusion.

Comment: /mɪlχ/ is also possible. At least by some rare individuals in the Westphalian area.

Comment: @Pekka "Badisch" is not actually a dialect. The northern part of Baden speaks Kurpfälzisch, where ch becomes sch. The south speaks Alemannisch, which is related to Schwitzerdütsch, and the inbetweens something that's very similar to the dialect of the neighbouring Swabian regions. "Baden" is more or less ;) an invention of Napoleon.

Answer (score 7):

Apart from certain slight speaking defects (probably comparable to a lisp), there are regional variations in pronunciation.

In Berlin and Brandenburg, for instance, some people even pronounce it "Mültsch" [mʏltʃ].

[mɪlç] is the correct pronunciation, though.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, *ch* is only [x] when used after a back vowel. It is pronounced as [ç] in all other locations (the two are allophones of the same phoneme with [ç] being the default). [ç] might sound like a [ʃ] to speakers of languages which do not have the [ç] phone.

As deceze points out, the German back vowels are [u], [a], and [o] and their unstressed variants. There are rare cases where a segment border stands between such a vowel and a following *ch* where the *ch* is pronounced as a [ç] (consider *Frauchen* ['fʁaʊ.ç<sup>ə</sup>n], a female owner of a dog, literally "little woman", where no phonetic variation occurs in the diminutive suffix), but other than that, the allophones occur in perfect complementary distribution.

Comment: Could you provide some sample words?  I have no idea what the back vowels are in German.

Comment: @Kyra Many `ach`, `uch` and `och` words are pronounced with an [x]: *ach*, *Bach*, *flach*, *Dach*, *lachen*, *huch*, *Fluch*, *fluchen*, *suchen*, *doch*, *Docht*, *Loch*, *kochen*. `ech` and `ich` are often (always?) pronounced with a [ç]: *echt*, *schlecht*, *Recht*, *Blech*, *ich*, *mich*, *dich*, *Milch*, *Knilch*...

Comment: @deceze e and i (and I believe all consonants) are always followed by [ç].

Comment: Consonants are followed by [ç]. The sound is the same *Milch* and *Knilch* as for *Molch* and *Mulch*.

Answer (score 2):

The Hessian, Palatinate and Rhine-Hessian regions of Germany actually do not use [ʃ] but rather [ʒ] for many ch sounds after front vowels.

And the pronounciation in Bavaria is often [mɪlx] – they use the [x] sound a lot more often than the more Northern Germans.

Answer (score 0):

Although [mɪlç] is the correct pronunciation in Standard German, it's quite common to hear other pronunciations. As pointed out by some, in Hessian, Badenian, Pfälzisch, Saarländisch and Kölsch, they often pronounce ch as /ʃ/. Sometimes this is a problem with hypercorrection, or the speakers just don't make [a very clear distinction](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rheinischer_Regiolekt) between these sounds.