# Gibt's eine Regel ob man "ch" als "sch" oder "ch" (asperiert) ausspricht?

Tags: pronunciation

Often I hear native speakers pronounce "Ich" to sound like "Isch". Is that one of the few exceptions to pronouncing the two consonants as in "Bach" where the sound is aspirated? Are there other cases where the pronunciation rhymes with "Fisch"? Is there a rule that one can rely on?

Comment: "Isch" in this case is a dialectical phonetic difference most found in the north and north-east of germany

Comment: FYI the duplicate is this one: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4519/how-is-ch-pronounced-correctly/4521#4521

Comment: @Vogel612: Ich kenne es von Köln und westlich davon. Wenn jetzt noch jmd. mit Süden aufwartet, dann wird es flächendeckend verwendet. :)

Comment: @userunknown da kann ich beruhigen, im süden ist es eher selten. nord-osten war schlichtweg falsch, da sagt man eher "icke"

Comment: @Vogel612 Wo im Norden sagt man denn "isch"? Ich kenne das aus dem Saarland und Umgebung (Pfalz).

Comment: @starblue für einen BW-ler ist das Norden, oder so ähnlich. hab da Mist verzapft :((