# How to pronounce "ich"

Tags: pronunciation, personal-pronoun

I've been learning German since October 2013. I know at some point I must decided how to pronounce "ich". Any opinions that might help me make this decision? Danke...

Comment: It is hard to provide any help with pronunciation in written form that goes beyond the phonetic transcription that can be found in most dictionaries.

Comment: I think you should go for the correct version ;)

Comment: Check out the audio files [here](http://www.dict.cc/?s=ich) (small speaker icon to the right).

Comment: Yes, thank you. I've listened to different pronunciations, but wanted opinions to help me decide which one.

Comment: @andy_5995.. as for standard German, there is only one, in fact. Why would you think there are different ones?

Comment: @Emanuel... because of different information I've read or heard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4519/how-is-ch-pronounced-correctly) and maybe [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/683/how-is-the-ending-ig-pronounced-and-where) question.

What applies to your question is

> /ç/ (as in ich, Mädchen)